# Javascript: Need help writing treeview (from either JSON or nested class list)

Tags: javascript, node.js, treeview

I'm trying to create a Treeview to enable/disable nodes. I'm writing a plugin for an application written in js, and as I've never used js or any other web development language, I'm trying to figure it out as I go along. I have a nested set of classes that I load in from a JSON file. The structure looks as follows:

```
{
"name": "TopLevel",
"subLists": 
[
   {
      "id": "A1",
      "enabled": true
      subLists: 
      [
         {
            "id:"A1.1",
            "enabled" : false,
            "subLists": []
         },
         {
            "id" : "A1.2",
            "enabled" : true,
            "sublists" : []
         }
      ]
   }
]
}
```

The imported JSON file is user-configurable and can have an arbitrary number of nested subLists. I would like the user to be able to browse through them in a treeview and toggle the "enabled" attribute of each.

When I look at the [treeview tutorial on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp), they show how to make a hardcoded list rather than one populated from an array or imported from an external JSON file. I also found the [jsTree resource](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.core.data), which does seem to be able to populate trees from JSON data, but it seems to need the JSON to come from a server and my JSON files are all local.

I'd ideally like to build a treeview that points to my script's TopLevel class in memory rather than directly at the JSON file to avoid having to reload the JSON every time the user enables/disables a branch. Could someone point me to a resource for learning how to do this?

Comment: `it seems to need the JSON to come from a server and my JSON files are all local` There's no difference. As long as you feed it with the required JSON, data's origin is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't really get what the syntax would look like. My best guess:

```
$('#using_json').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : myJsonfile.json
     
} });
```

Am I close?

Comment: No, you can't call a file directly like this. Direct file system access is extremely restricted by browsers, for obvious security reasons. You need [a way to get the JSON data](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) first. Then in your attempt above, replace `myJsonfile.json` with your actual data and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

it's great that you learn js in practice and this is a very good exercise.
I can show you how to do this in pure JS without jsTree as I believe it's better to learn to do such things in pure JS.

The first thing to note here is that you have to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) in order to handle an arbitrary number of nested subLists. This means that we have to write a function that renders a tree node and then calls itself for each child node.

Heres an example that I came up with. (I've modified the input JSON a little bit - fixed a typo and renamed "name" to "id" in the topLevel node.)

```js
const DATA = {
"id": "TopLevel",
"subLists": 
[
   {
      "id": "A1",
      "enabled": true,
      "subLists" : 
      [
         {
            "id":"A1.1",
            "enabled" : false,
            "subLists": [
              {
                "id": "A1.2",
                "enabled": false,
                "subLists": []
              }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id" : "A1.2",
            "enabled" : true,
            "subLists" : []
         }
      ]
   }
]
};

function renderNode(node, target) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = node.id;
  target.append(li);
  if(node.subLists && node.subLists.length) {
    const ul = document.createElement('ul');
    li.append(ul)
    node.subLists.forEach( (subList) => {
      renderNode(subList, ul);
    } );
  }
}


const root = document.getElementById('root');

renderNode(DATA, root);
```

```html
<ul id="root">
</ul>
```

Now regarding the "enabled" property. I guess you want branches to be folded or unfolded based on this. You can achieve this reusing the code from w3schools which you've linked. A separate script could handle folding and unfolding the branches.

I hope this will help ;)